# JDBC selecting a sequence

Tags: jdbc, transactions, mule

I need to call a webservice and the response needs to be inserted into a DB parent table which has a sequence as key. Also I need to select that sequence number just inserted and insert the data into 2 child tables all in one transaction. How could this be achieved? I can do all inserts in a transaction but I need to do a select to get the sequence after the first insert into the parent table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by wrapping all of your calls into a transaction.  There are several exception strategies available, but it sounds like a simple rollback strategy would work for you.  If any of the calls in the transactional block generate an exception, the exception strategy will be triggered.  Keep in mind that if you want your web service call to throw an exception on failure, you will need to check the status code and generate the exception if it isn't what you expect.

```
<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">

        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="getSequenceNumber" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="myConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN" />
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${webServiceHost}" 
            port="${webServicePort}" 
            path="${webServicePath}" 
            method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
         </http:outbound-endpoint>

         <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="createRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="myConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN" />
         </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>

        <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" />
    </transactional>
```

You can read more about more transactions here:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management